# Is there a single regex pattern that allows for either all numbers or all letters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation

I'm not very familiar with regex yet, but I'm attempting to validate the format of an temperature input and the requirement is that the user can either type a floating point number (digits on the left and right of a decimal point) OR a description of the temperature (something like "ambient").

Is this possible to do in one regex?  The reason I ask is that I'm attempting to validate a rails model column (`validates :temperature, format: { with: ... }`).

I'm also aware that you can have custom validations for your model, but it looks like you can't apply that to a single field's validation, but rather the model's validation in general.  Please let me know if I'm wrong about this.

Any and all help is appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the input.  That doesn't work for me though because that's not a single regex.

Comment: I'm not sure who is doing the downvoting.  I appreciate everyone's answers so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All digits (floating point) or all letters:

```
^(\d+(\.\d+)?|[a-zA-Z]+)$
```

Comment: Could you describe to me how these two answers differ?  Do they both work the same despite being slightly different from each other syntax-wise?

Comment: @JakeSmith this regex will match `12` ie integers as well whereas the other one will not.

Comment: @JakeSmith: Only difference being that this regex allows `123` as well as `123.45` whereas other one always enforces a floating point number.

Comment: Rails is giving me this message when testing the validation: `The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ and $), which may present a security risk.  Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?`  I can create a new question if that is necessary, but if you could explain to me what it means by multiline, that would be great.  Would replacing the multiline characters with the ones they suggested work still?

Comment: New question is not needed. You can certainly use `:multiline => true` or may be `(?m)^(\d+(\.\d+)?|[a-zA-Z]+)$`

Comment: thanks for your help.  Feel free to stop answering my questions, but I'm still trying to understand this a little better.  Right now '4.2ambient' is passing validation, whereas, I have a test that asserts that '4.2ambient' is not a valid value for this field.  I've been using [http://www.regexr.com/] to test these out and it actually seems like rails uses these regexs a little differently than I would expect.  The site regexr.com seems to separate the '4.2' and the 'ambient', but Rails does not...

Comment: If you're using anchors `^` and `$` then `'4.2ambient` cannot match this. I don't write code in rails I know a bit of Ruby and can provide you some demo links where `'4.2ambient` will not match with above regex.

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?:\d+\.\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)$
```

You can use anchors and or operator to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks!  I went with the other one so that the decimal point was not required!